# Xcode: Stop Unit testing process after all test cases are executed

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have a test case file which has 3 tests.

```
- (void)test1DataFetchValidCase {
    //fetch list from server using dispatch_async for valid lat & lon coordinates. expected response is an array of 20 values.
}

- (void)test2DataFetchInvalidCase {
    //fetch list from server using dispatch_async for invalid lat & lon coordinates. expected response is nil
}

- (void)test3NameFetch {
    //fetch list of names from server using dispatch_async for valid lat & lon coordinates.
}
```

Since I've given names like test1, test2, test3 it is certain that Xcode will run the tests in this order. The console will show this by executing in that order.

However, after test3NameFetch which is successful, the spinner keeps spinning and the testing process never stops. I have to manually press the stop button to see

> Executed 3 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.012 (0.013) seconds

How to stop the test process once all test cases are executed?

Comment: Can you confirm the presence of tearDown() method in your test class?

Comment: yup, it is there. should I call [self tearDown] in the last method?

Comment: No. The Setup() and tearDown() methods get called automatically for each test method. Is there any synchronous call or any blocking function you are calling on the main thread in your tests? Some detail here would help.

Comment: added what tasks the functions perform. I use dispatch_async to fetch, so there is no blocking function.